# Do I need to pay taxes in the US as an Alien Resident for my Canadian stock capital gains

Tags: united-states, stocks, canada, foreign-income

I'm about to pull the trigger and get some Canadian stock `BBI:CA`, but first I want to know if I need to pay special taxes, or If I'll be double taxed by this capital gains.

- I'm a US alien, got the residence for 2 years and now I'm about to get the permanent one.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer my own question. After calling my broker, they explained me this:

- For dividends earnings, Canada government withholds 15%. That could be used as credit for US taxes
- For stock, you're only taxed once by the IRA. It works just like a US stock.

Comment: To add a reference to this, the reason for the difference in tax treatment lies in the tax treaty between the US and Canada. This is a complex area and a quick answer online is insufficient for full support, without knowing the OP's full situation. However in short, between the US & Canada, capital gains [excluding 'real property', like land) are considered income in the country where the individual is a resident [not the country where the stocks exist]. So Canada does not generally have the right to tax a US resident's capital gains income.